# Как из сделать взяимосвязи между людьми из одной таблицы? Django

Tags: python, sql, django

Есть основная таблица Users, там находятся все зарегистрированные пользователи
Среди этих пользователей есть начальники и подчинённые. У начальников могут быть подчинённые. Как это грамотно связать через ещё одну таблицу?
На мой придуманные метод Django ругается, но и очевидно что это не очень решение

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Relationship(models.Model):
    promo = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Попробуйте задать related_name для полей.  В таком случае, у меня всё работает

Comment: Спасибо, помогло